# Using DNN authentication and authorization info from another ASP.NET app

Tags: asp.net, content-management-system, dotnetnuke

I have an ASP.NET web application "K" that has its own authentication and authorization built on SimpleMembershipProvider.

Now I want to set up a web site that has application "K" and DNN, in a way that the user will log in to DNN app and I have a button within DNN app that will jump to app "K".

Within "K", I would like to implement these behaviors.

1. If the user is not logged in, go back to DNN's home page.
2. If the user is logged in but does not have a "K-user" role in DNN, show "contact administrator" message.
3. If the user is logged in and have "K-user" role in DNN, allow the user to use the app as usual.

This is brand new site so I do not have any constraint. I can put "K" under DNN (or vice versa, but not sure why I would do it that way), I can put "K" next to DNN and give the same machineKey to share cookies, I don't even have to use DNN, it can be any CMS as long as it has nice and easy way to fill in information.

I must be using wrong keyword on my googling. It seems very basic need but can't find exact article that can show me how to do it.

Any helps would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I solved it.

- Put DNN and "K" as direct child siblings of web root.
- Make DNN and "K" have the same MachineKey.
- Write [User Migration sql script](https://gist.github.com/kennethchoe/8867571), from DNN to "K".
- Make a link from DNN to "K".
- Modify "K" web.config authentication section like below. Key point is loginUrl and name.

>

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="/dnn/Login.aspx" defaultUrl="~/" name=".DOTNETNUKE" protection="All" timeout="60" cookieless="UseCookies" />
</authentication>
```

- Disable any code in "K" that allows the user to log in directly to "K".
- When the user visits "K" for the first time, execute user migration sql script. (you could initiate migration script in any moment that fits you the most.)

Now, the user will log in onto DNN, and click a link to access "K". When this happens, "K" can behave as if the user actually logged in using "K" application, like reading roles from Web.Security, etc. That comes for free since you made its forms authentication cookie name and MachineKey synced between two applications.

Comment: I am looking to do something similar, and in your solution I am not clear whether DNN and "K" must use the same database, i.e. the same aspnet_user etc tables.

Comment: @Apeksha you don't have to use the same database, and in fact separate database is better choice. You have to use user migration script as I mentioned to sync up users, but that way you are loosely coupled with DNN. I ended up not using DNN at all and just implement my own security management and payment processing, since DNN was super slow compared to hand-written codes and payment processing modules were not as flexible to meet my need.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need to modify the authentication method of your "K" application.  Then, you could build a module that takes care of the behaviors based on whether the user is logged in and is in a certain role.

Once you log into DNN and check the roles, your user needs to be authenticated to the "K" website.

We do something similar, but it required that our "internal" site would accept a token as proof of who the user was and they were authenticated.

Here is an example of what we do:

- Both sites must check for cookie/Token

  - If token exists, refresh it.  If not, create cookie/token
- "Internal" site checks for cookie and uses value to authenticate to Token database
- Subsequent requests read the token from the cookie and validate against Token database
- When user logs out, cookie and database entry are deleted
- If user does not log out properly, you must clean up tokens on a set interval

Comment: I can use any existing CMS, but it will be better if I don't have to customize CMS part. DNN is popularly used so I wonder if there is a way to do this with existing DNN package. And then again, with any existing CMS packages.

Comment: If security is not a huge issue, you could just turn on the UsersOnline feature [or read the dnn SiteLog table] to have the "K" app determine if the user is online and authenticate them that way.  You could then have it read the users, userroles, and roles table to determine if the user was a member of a certain group.  Then, have it handle the behaviors you mentioned.  

There are a lot of different ways you could handle this depending on your setup and requirements.  DNN doesn't provide everything, but it is very flexible for special situations.  I've done A LOT of cross site integrations.