# Authentication model in dotnetnuke

Tags: authentication, dotnetnuke

I want to compare authentication methods in asp.identity and dotnetnuke. I have read very articles about authentication in dotnetnuke.

[DNN AUTHENTICATION WITH NEW ASP.NET IDENTITY SYSTEM](http://www.dnnsoftware.com/answers/dnn-authentication-with-new-aspnet-identity-system)

[DotNetNuke Tips and Tricks #12: Creating your own Authentication Provider](http://www.dnnsoftware.com/community-blog/cid/134678/dotnetnuke-tips-and-tricks-12-creating-your-own-authentication-provider)

[Using DNN authentication and authorization info from another ASP.NET app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21131243/using-dnn-authentication-and-authorization-info-from-another-asp-net-app)

[How to Setup the Authentication Settings in DotNetNuke](http://www.dnncreative.com/Tutorials/DNNTutorialsforAdministrators/AuthenticationSettings/tabid/461/Default.aspx)

But I din't understand authentication elements and the relationship between them.

It would be very helpful if someone could explain authentication method in dotnetnuke.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

DotNetNuke uses Asp.Net Membership not Identity.  To replace the core authentication provider would be a lot of effort.

There are several ways to create your own authentication provider, but ultimately it will still be using the DotNetNuke Asp.Net Membership process.  If you want to use an external service that uses Asp.Net Identity you could have your external Asp.Net Identity service pass a token/cookie to a custom DotNetNuke authentication/redirect module that validates the token/cookie, migrates the user from the Asp.Net Identity database to the DotNetNuke Asp.Net Membership database and finally does the login: DotNetNuke.Entities.Users.UserController.UserLogin.